# Visual studio code сброс сочетаний клавиш

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Работаю в visual studio code под linux. Немного поигрался с сочетаниями клавиш и теперь хочу сбросить всё в настройки по умолчанию, но не понимаю - как это можно сделать?

Comment: У вас кастомизация вся в `keybindings.json`. Насколько я помню, все новые сочетания хранятся там. Очистите и заполните теми которые нужны.

Comment: Данный файл у меня чист. Переустановка VSC не помогает. Видимо конфигурация сохраняется где-то ещё.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: Еще тут можно поискать: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: [Вот тут конкретно описано как сбрасывать кастомные настройки.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule)

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой в Visual Studio Code, только под Windows. Нашел простое решение. Захожу в главном меню Файл -> Параметры -> Сочетания клавиш. В открывшейся вкладке, в поле "Введите текст для поиска в сочетаниях клавиш" набираю "Пользователь". Выходит список строк в которых встречается это слово. Нахожу строки у которых значение столбца "Исходная база" соответствует названию "Пользователь". Щелкаю правой кнопкой мыши и в контекстном меню выбираю "Сбросить настраиваемое сочетание клавиш". Эта строка может пропасть из вызванного мной сортированного списка, так как в её столбце "Исходная база" уже нет названия "Пользователь", оно поменялось на "По умолчанию" и соответственно сочетание клавиш.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нажимаете правой кнопкой по этой строке и выбираете "сбросить настраиваемое сочетание клавиш"